# vue фильтрация списка

Tags: vue.js

Есть некий список и фильтр этого списка [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7or0rn3lx):

```
<template>
  <div id="filter">
    <h1>Filter List</h1>

    <div class="filter-panel">
      <ul class="filter-list">
        <li :key="index" v-for="(ch, index) in checkboxOptions">
          <label>
            <input 
              type="checkbox" 
              v-model="ch.selected" 
               :value="ch.value">
            <span> {{ ch.text }} </span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <ul class="filter-list">
        <li :key="index" v-for="(r, index) in radioOptions">
          <label>
            <input 
              type="radio" 
              v-model="selected" 
               :value="r.value">
            <span> {{ r.text }}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <transition-group name="fade" mode="out-in" tag="ul" class="catalog-list">
      <li :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in filterItems">
        <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
        <span>{{ item.price }}</span>
      </li>
    </transition-group>

  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>

export default {
  name: "FilterList",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { name: "Name 1", price: "200" },
        { name: "Name 2", price: "100" },
        { name: "Name 3", price: "5" }
      ],
      selected: "all",
      radioOptions: [
        { text: 'All', value: 'all' },
        { text: 'Filter Name 1', value: 'Name 1' },
        { text: 'Filter Name 2', value: 'Name 2' },
        { text: 'Filter Name 3', value: 'Name 3' }
      ],
      checkboxOptions: [
        { text: 'Filter 200', value: '200', selected: false },
        { text: 'Filter 100', value: '100', selected: false },
        { text: 'Filter 5', value: '5', selected: false }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filterItems() {
      var vm = this,
          name = vm.selected;

      var currentItems = vm.items;

      if(name !== "all"){      
        currentItems = currentItems.filter(function(n){
          return n.name === name;
        });
      }     

      vm.checkboxOptions.forEach( function(option) { 
        if (option.selected) {
          currentItems = currentItems.filter(function(m) { 
            return m.price === option.value;
           });
         }
      });

      return currentItems;

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Фильтр состоит из радиокнопок и чекбоксов. Фильтрация по имени `name` и по цене `price`.

Фильтрация происходит, но нужно чтобы при выборе чекбоксов, например 100 и 200, то пункты списка с 100 и 200 должны оставаться, а не исчезать оба.

**Вопрос:** как использовать и `input[type=radio]` и `input[type=checkbox]` для фильтрации списка, как произвести фильтрация `price` с использованием чекбоксов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо следующую часть кода (в нём мы проходим по всем чекбоксам и для каждого чекбокса фильтруем список по этому чекбоксу):

```
vm.checkboxOptions.forEach( function(option) { 
  if (option.selected) {
    currentItems = currentItems.filter(function(m) { 
      return m.price === option.value;
     });
   }
});
```

Заменить на код, который будет **один раз** фильтровать список по условию «значение элемента списка входит в множество значений выделенных чекбоксов»:

```
const selectedChecboxesValues = vm.checkboxOptions
    .filter(option => option.selected)
    .map(option => option.value)

if (selectedChecboxesValues.length > 0) {
    currentItems = currentItems.filter(item => 
                       selectedChecboxesValues.includes(item.price));
}
```